# How to resize an Image from a Theme folder with Twig/Timber in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber, twig-filter

I am having great difficulties getting an image resized using Twig/Timber in Wordpress, here is my code - is there something I am missing?

`<img src="{{ theme.path ~ '/images/dog.jpg' | resize(250) }}">` it just outputs `wordpress.local/wp-content/themes/custom-theme/images/dog.jpg` instead of `wordpress.local/wp-content/themes/custom-theme/images/dog-250x0.jpg`

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image doesn't part of WordPress theme, I mean, it is but it's not been handled by WordPress Media Library using `wp_handle_upload` or similar approach.

Timber documentation [says](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/cookbook-images/#basic-image-stuff)

> All of these filters [* - `resize`, `letterbox`] are written specifically to interact with WordPress’s image API. So don’t worry, no weird TimThumb stuff going on—this is all using WordPress’s internal image sizing stuff.

That mean your images need to be uploaded by WordPress itself with all picture metadata - not just present inside your theme or even `uploads` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - so do I have any resizing options at all then for images in the theme/images folder, other than cropping and resizing manually? (these are default images in case one does not get attached it will put this one in place and they need to be a certain size to match with others on the page.)

Comment: You may create customizer settings or options for default images upload them and they will be available for resizing. But this way they can be deleted by user. At the end manual cropping is the only option for 'eternal' (undeletable) backups as far as I know